# NoneType Error being raised when performing math operation

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, nonetype

```
math.floor(16*((a*tl[i][0]+c)%m/(10**math.floor(math.log10((a*tl[i][0]+c)%m))+1)))
```

This line of code keeps returning the exception "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable," and I'm not sure why. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when you try to subscript (i.e. use square brackets `[]`) a `None`. For example:

```
>>> x = None
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Make sure that `tl` is not `None` and `tl[i][0]` is not `None` for all `i`.